# Copying an object of same class with different foreign key id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am writing a method to copy an Object with a different foreign key id. 
So There are these 2 classes GroupAccount and GroupCanvas. One GroupAccount can have many GroupCanvas'es . So, when I say, I want to copy a GroupCanvas, then I would like to create a new object of GroupCanvas with all the values same as inside the previous GroupCanvas. Is there some way to do a cascaded copy because GroupCanvas has child objects too which I want to copy? 
I am posting my SQL code, kindly have a look :

```
CREATE TABLE groupaccount
(
  groupid numeric NOT NULL,
  groupname character varying,
  adminusername character varying,
  blacklist character varying[],
  CONSTRAINT groupid PRIMARY KEY (groupid)
)

CREATE TABLE membercanvas
(
  groupcanvasid integer NOT NULL,
  mcanvasname character varying,
  mcanvasnumber numeric,
  mcanvastitle character varying,
  mcanvasdate character varying,
  mcanvascreator character varying,
  mcanvasiteration character varying,
  groupid numeric NOT NULL,
  memberid integer NOT NULL,
  mcanvasimage bytea,
  sortorder numeric DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT mcanvasid PRIMARY KEY (groupcanvasid),
  CONSTRAINT groupaccount_membercanvas_fk FOREIGN KEY (groupid)
      REFERENCES groupaccount (groupid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT groupmembers_membercanvas_fk FOREIGN KEY (memberid)
      REFERENCES groupmembers (memberid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
CREATE TABLE membersection
(
  msectionid integer NOT NULL,
  msectionname character varying,
  mxposition integer,
  myposition integer,
  groupcanvasid integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT msectionid PRIMARY KEY (msectionid),
  CONSTRAINT membercanvas_membersection_fk FOREIGN KEY (groupcanvasid)
      REFERENCES membercanvas (groupcanvasid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, for this purpose, you would use a [copy constructor](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12)

But if you need to obtain a copy only in a certain context than its better to implement a service method and take control over what you copy. Being the same objects, you can get a way with just a few lines by using spring's [BeanUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html)

from the docs

```
copyProperties(Object source, Object target)
```

> Copy the property values
>   of the given source bean into the target bean.

and

```
copyProperties(Object source, Object target, String... ignoreProperties)
```

> Copy the property values of the given source bean
>   into the given target bean, ignoring the given "ignoreProperties".

Comment: Thanks. THis sounds easy. :-) One unrelated question : I have a DAO method where I am using session.merge(entityName) to save an entity, can I call entityName.getId() after session.flush() ?? Will I get the Id, it works for session.save(), I don't know about session.merge().